# How to remove question mark icon on folders when git is installed in Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu-16.04

I have problem regarding git. When it is installed in my Ubuntu all desktop files and folders are having Question mark/help icon on it

**Image**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this commands and Shutdown my system and then icons are gone.But is it a good method?????

```
sudo apt-get purge runit
sudo apt-get purge git-all
sudo apt-get purge git
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you have a `.git` folder in your `$HOME` or `$HOME/Desktop` directory: you should not create a git repo in there, so you can delete it (or rename it for safekeeping just in case)

Once removed, the question marks should disappear.